# Appending an environmental variable, oops what did I do?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

This may seem pretty hilarious, but why did this happen?  In the first line I was appending an existing local user variable, and in the second line I get a continuation prompt (it looks the same with a different color in my terminal).  Why the continuation prompt?  How do I exit this expression properly?  And how would you properly append a variable with the output of a command? pwd >> $joe doesn't work.

```
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ joe=$joe\`pwd`
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ 
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ ;
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ 
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ 
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ ^[
-bash: :s^[: substitution failed
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ 
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ exit
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ ,
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ 
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ 
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ exit
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $ ls
rcharette station-2-87 ~ $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape char (backslash ) causes the next char to be interpreted as a literal. So the \ before the ' on the first line causes the ' to be treated as a literal instead of, well, and open quote. Therefore the second ' is actually the open quote and everything after that is treated as a literal string.

Why did you add the backslash? Just remove it and it should work.

Barry

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have an unmatched backtick. You're escaping the first one, so it's the second one that actually begins the backticked string.

Answer (score 1):

```
joe=$joe\`pwd`
```

will be seen as looking for a variable with the literal name `joe\'pwd`, since you've escaped the first backtick. The second backtick begins a subshell command, but there's no further text, so you get the continuation prompt. If you're trying to insert a literal \ into the new variable, then you'll have to escape it:

```
joe=$joe\\`pwd`
```

which would give you something like

```
joe=hello/home/users/etc...
```

If you're trying to build a path dynamically, use a `/` instead... unix paths don't use backslashes.